# How do different technologies connect to form a web stack?

Tags: java, python, web-applications, mvc, web-services

I am a little confused, is it possible to implement a front end using common languages like html, css and javascript and then do server side processing using a language of your choice, say python or java?

I am aware of what a LAMP stack is; I'm aware that rails is a full stack framework; I'm aware that you can use things like spring MVC and Grails. But I'm not sure how you would combine technologies of your choice.

For example:

- Java has a great API that you can do a lot with, but is not really the best choice for developing front end stuff in a non enterprise environment.
- Python has great libraries for processing and visualizing data (yes I know about django).

I suspect that this is when you want to use a custom technology stack you have to create a RESTful or SOAP API or just pass data using XML or JSON...

Would someone be able to clarify if my understanding is correct?

Comment: I am currently developing a project with handlebars and node.js. You can easily swap the backend, cause the frontend has no relation to the backend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... is it possible to implement a front end using common languages like html, css and javascript and then do server side processing using a language of your choice, say python or java?

Yes, it is possible. It is standard, in fact.

> But I'm not sure how you would combine technologies of your choice.

When an HTTP request is received by your web server process it forwards that to your back-end (Java or Python code), which then returns content (like HTML). The web server transmits an HTTP response back to the web browser.

There are a variety of ways that your web server could communicate with your back-end code. It could host it directly, like via WSGI, or I suppose you could use some form of [Inter-process Communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Comment: Don' forget HTML form submission, which could execute some Java.

Comment: @Mawg: Are you referring to applets, or server-side Java? Nobody should use applets anymore. A form submission is just an HTTP POST, which follows the same pathway as what I described above.